# Changing the position of a line using QPainter

Tags: python, qt, pyqt4, qpainter, qtgui

I have a window with a push-button. Once the button is clicked , I would like to change the position of line that is initially drawn.This is my code till now.

```
import sys 
from PyQt4 import QtGui , QtCore

class trial(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(trial , self).__init__()
        self.window()

    def window(self):
        self.a = 0
        button = QtGui.QPushButton('Push')
        button.setCheckable(True)
        button.clicked.connect(self.fun)
        grid = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        grid.addWidget(button , 0 , 0)
        self.setLayout(grid)
        self.setWindowTitle('Trial')
        self.setGeometry(500 , 500 , 500 , 500)
        self.show()

    def fun(self , text):
        if text == 1:
            self.a = 0

        else:
            self.a = 1


    def paintEvent(self , e):
        qp = QtGui.QPainter()
        qp.begin(self)
        pen = QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.red , 5 , QtCore.Qt.SolidLine)
        qp.setPen(pen)

        if self.a == 0:

            qp.drawLine(20 , 20 , 20 , 480)
        else:
            qp.drawLine(480 , 20 , 480 , 480) 
        qp.end()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    t = trial()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I know my code looks a bit awkward but I'm facing the following problems.
1. It takes quite a bit of time after the button is pressed for the line to change position.

2.Also how do I rub the line that is previously drawn.

It would be nice if someone could modify the code for me.Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Add a call to `self.update()` in your `fun()` function to let Qt know that your widget needs to be redrawn

2) (Not totally sure on the python syntax, so I'll give the example in C++)

You can paint the background explicitly in your paint event:

```
qp.setBrush( Qt::white );  // Or whatever color you want the background to be 
qp.drawRect( rect() );
```

or you can try messing with [QWidget::setAutoFillBackground()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#autoFillBackground-prop)